# Hide radio button while keeping its functionality

Tags: html, css

I searched on SO and Google and I couldn't find anything related. Is there any way I can hide the radio button next to an image (that is used as a label for it) but still keep its functionality when clicking on the label?

I have tried several methods but it seems that using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` makes the radio function useless.

Comment: It's in the post. "using display:none or visibility:hidden makes the radio function useless"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cover them with another div whose color matched with the background. This will hide the radio buttons and still your radio buttons will work on clicks of their labels. Hope that helps..

Comment: Or else you can work without radio buttons also. If you need only labels on whose click will give you the required operations to be performed, then directly use divs instead of radio buttons and set onclick actions to these divs.

Comment: That's the only solution I could think of as well. Unless I get a better answer I will accept yours. Thank you!

Comment: I need them in the OpenCart's product.tpl. It seems that the easiest option is still covering them with an image...

Comment: I meant these are generated dynamically and I would waste more time working out the solution in the comment than the one in your main answer. From these two options I'd go with the first one -> less developing time, deadlines suck.

Comment: That's up to you. You can do as you please. And also if this satisfied your problem, don't forgot to accept the answer. :)

Comment: Too much work. [It can be done](https://jsfiddle.net/y56mqtd3/2/) using `position:fixed; opacity:0;`

Answer (score 11):

> I have tried several methods but it seems that using display:none or visibility:hidden makes the radio function useless.

But it works. Maybe you didn't set `for` attribute:

```
<input id=radio1 name=testradios type=radio><label for=radio1>radio1</label>
<br>
<input id=radio2 name=testradios type=radio><label for=radio2>radio2</label>

#radio1 {
    display: none;
}
```

OR

```
#radio1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Both hide radio button but label is still clickable and checks its radiobutton.

http://jsfiddle.net/m0fbd75w/

Comment: That is really weird. I only tried it with Inspect Element, have to try it in the files and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @MateiPanchios In Firefox and Chromium (Chrome), the inspection tab isn't updated to show which item is selected when you click on the radio button

Comment: The problem is using it as "required". Chrome generates an error "An invalid form control with name='...' is not focusable."

Comment: WARNING: Don't use either of these approaches as they are not accessible. You cannot select them with the keyboard and they don't show up in the accessibility tree.

Answer (score 9):

In Angular, `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` didn't work for me.
Instead, I used:

```
input[type=radio] {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Upvote because this allows the "required" attribute to keep working

Comment: AND it preserves keyboard navigation/selection. Just need to apply proper styling to the visible wrapper element to show that the transparent radio/checkbox has focus.

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.getElementById('myId').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(this.checked);
})
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
label:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150') no-repeat;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="myId">
<label for="myId"></label>
```