# How to create a select input with the options horizontally aligned?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, radio-button

I basically want to create a **select element**, where the **options** are **displayed next to each other horizontally**. Like this:
[image]

How can I implement this design?

Answer (score 0):

Using a basic form a radio button would be one way to do it and then hide the actual input using css while keeping the label

[Hide radio button while keeping its functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346385/hide-radio-button-while-keeping-its-functionality)

then you are just styling the labels how you want them

```
 <form action="form action goes here">
   <input type="radio" value="1">
   <label for="1">1</label> 
   <input type="radio" value="2">
   <label for="2">2</label> 
   <input type="radio" value="3">
   <label for="3">3</label> 
   <input type="radio" value="1">
   <label for="3">3</label> 
...and so on
</form>
```